# What is wrong with the following java methods?

Tags: java, dom, dom4j

I am trying to translate the Javascript function [here.](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3754)

This will produce a cardinal xpath string given a org.w3c.dom.DOMElement: `/html/body/p[3]/a`

`getElementXpath` works fine if I comment out the `getElementIdx()` function and the conditional. Problem seems to be located in `getElementIdx()`, but I don't see what I am doing wrong, the Java code below is nearly same as the Javascript version.

What happens is that an empty string is returned! I tried printing out the path inside the `getElementXpath` function but to no avil. Expected output is a cardinal xpath string!

Update:

```
public static String getElementXpath(DOMElement elt){
        String path = ""; 

        for (; elt != null && elt.ELEMENT_NODE == elt.getNodeType(); elt = (DOMElement) elt.getParentNode()){

            path = "test";
            System.out.println(path); //this prints out fine.
        }
        System.out.println(path); //nothing is printed!
            return path;                            
    }
```

Why isn't path being printed, outside of the for loop???

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    DOMDocument domDocument = (DOMDocument) browser.getDocument();
                        DOMElement currentElement = (DOMElement) domDocument.getElementFromId("uniqueLink");                      
                                System.out.println(getElementXpath(currentElement));

}

public static String getElementXpath(DOMElement elt){
    String path = ""; 

    for (; elt != null && elt.ELEMENT_NODE == elt.getNodeType(); elt = (DOMElement) elt.getParentNode()){
        int idx = getElementIdx(elt);
        String xname = elt.getTagName();

        if (idx > 1) xname += "[" + idx + "]";
        path = "/" + xname + path;  

    }
    System.out.println(path);
        return path;                            
}

public static int getElementIdx(DOMElement elt) {
        int count = 1;

         for (DOMElement sib = (DOMElement) elt.getPreviousSibling(); sib != null; sib = (DOMElement) sib.getPreviousSibling())
            {
                if(sib.ELEMENT_NODE == sib.getNodeType() && sib.getTagName().equals(elt.getTagName())){

                    count++;
                }
            }       
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: You haven't told us what's going wrong, which makes it harder to answer...

Comment: @Kim: I very much doubt that *no* output string is returned - unless it's looping forever, or it doesn't go into the loop at all. Which of those is occurring? Or is it something else? What's being printed by the getElementIdx method? You've got quite a lot of diagnostics, but you're not telling us anything about what they're showing.

Comment: As a side note your logic looks wrong - if called on a first sibling the returned xpath will select that node *and* all its siblings. I don't think this is what you want. No idea why it's not returning anything though.

Comment: @CurtainDog, what should I use instead of getPreviousSibling.

Comment: @KJW - I'd just drop the `if (idx > 1)` unless you had a good reason for making the xpath cleaner. Another thing you might like to do is to inspect the id of the elements. If you get an element with an id you can start your xpath from there without having to walk all the way up to the root.

Comment: CurtainDog, yes, I am certainly inspecting the id of the elements first, but in some documents, you may not have such privilege, so the only way to locate that element is via counting it's siblings and selecting by index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *only* reason for getting an empty String is that this expression evaluates to false:

```
elt != null && elt.ELEMENT_NODE == elt.getNodeType()
```

So either the element you pass to the method is actually `null` or the elements node type is not identical with `elt.ELEMENT_NODE`. In all other cases, the result would be `/` at least.

But because your passing an instance of `DOMElement`, the node should always be of `ELEMENT_NODE` type, so I pretty sure, that `domDocument.getElementFromId("uniqueLink")` returns `null` for you current document. I'd check this first.

---

*For clarification*

```
public static String getElementXpath(DOMElement elt){
    String path = ""; 
    try {
      for (; elt != null && elt.ELEMENT_NODE == elt.getNodeType(); elt = (DOMElement) elt.getParentNode()){
        int idx = getElementIdx(elt);
        String xname = elt.getTagName();    
        if (idx > 1) {
           xname += "[" + idx + "]";
        }
        path = "/" + xname + path;  
        System.out.println("Inside: " + path);  // **1**
      }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // unhides any exception thrown inside the for loop
        e.printStackTrace();   
    } finally {
        // forces a final print of "path", even if a runtime exception was raised
        System.out.println("Outside: " + path); // **2**
    }
    return path;                            
}
```

In this snippet, you see *non-empty* paths at `**1**` and *empty* paths at `**2**`? Please double check your actual code, if it is the same as the code you've pasted into the question

Comment: in GetElementByXpath(), if I print inside the for loop, the `path` string variable is not empty. when I print the `path` string variable outside of the for loop, it's empty.....

Comment: still same. Inside prints out expected xpath strings. `System.out.println("Outside: " + path)` doesn't even run....I tried printing stuff out after the for loop, but nothing runs after the loop finishes....meaning return path is not even run. I don't see why there's not even an exception that is raised???

Comment: Is the loop actually finishing? The only other reason I can think of that the finally code wouldn't be executed is if someone is calling `System.exit()` which is unlikely given your code.

Comment: @CurtainDog - sorry for confusing you, I added the try-catch-finally blocks with my last edit after Kims last comment. Just to provide some debug code to reveal *why* the inner print statement is execute while the outer isn't.